# access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\dotnetzip-uxoebj5p.tmp' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to save a zip file with a web api which is throwing exception :

```
Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\DotNetZip-uxoebj5p.tmp' is 
denied.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String 
maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, 
FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean 
bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
```

at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, 
   Boolean bFromProxy at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
    at Ionic.Zip.SharedUtilities.CreateAndOpenUniqueTempFile(String dir, Stream& 
    fs, String& filename)
    at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.get_WriteStream()
    at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
    at Archnies.Archnies.DownloadFile(String url)

Code :

```
            Logger.LogMessage("Downloading File From URL " + url);
            // Construct HTTP request to get the file
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

            for (int i = 0; i <= driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                System.Net.Cookie ck = new System.Net.Cookie(driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Name, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Value, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Path, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Domain);
                httpRequest.CookieContainer.Add(ck);
            }
            String userAgent = (String)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return navigator.userAgent;");
            httpRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
            httpRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;// "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";

            //HttpStatusCode responseStatus;
            // Get back the HTTP response for web server
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

            //  Define buffer and buffer size
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            // Read from response and write to file
            string userProfile = Configurations.AppDataPath; //Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            byte[] b = null;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    //count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    count = httpResponseStream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                } while (httpResponseStream.CanRead && count > 0);//while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);
                b = ms.ToArray();
            }
            string fileName = Path.Combine(userProfile, String.Format("archaniesReport{0}.zip", new Random().Next(512365412)));
            Logger.LogMessage("File: " + fileName);
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
            zip.AddEntry(fileName, b);

            zip.Save(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            zip.Dispose();
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
            {
                while ((bytesRead = httpResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            File.Copy(Path.GetFileName(fileName), fileName, true);
            return true;
```

I also tried

```
 zip.TempFileFolder = Configurations.AppDataPath;
```

but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Kindly , let me know

Comment: Check if file or folder has permission.

Comment: I can't give permissions to 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv', it doesn't allow me to give folder permission under C:\\Windows

Comment: You have to move the file outside where you have enough permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file to temporary location, which you get using `Path.GetTempPath()` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx)). After the download is complete, you can move file by `File.Copy(...)` to user's folder and delete file from temp by `File.Delete(...)`.

Using this approach you won't get acces denied exception.

Comment: I am trying to save the file in AppData of the IIS Directory, which it has complete permission , I believe the dotnetzip libarary is installed on windows directory, which IIS Server has not access to and thus it is throwing exception

What can be the solution?

Comment: So `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` is correct solution?